# Add value to New column if condition and group it MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get data from database where in 1 table i have a column that divide the price for the product id based on 0 and 1, but on group it by a desired column that value is not populated to the New column.

My question is, how can i add the value to the new column if condition by grouped values:

Database:

```
Column 1:
id,generic,name,size
1,SS,Test,S
2,SS,Test 2,M
3,SS,Test 3,L

Column 2:
id,product_id,is_valued,price
1,1,0,199
2,1,1,159
3,2,0,599
4,3,0,599
```

So, in mysql i do:

```
SELECT column2.price, (CASE WHEN column2.is_valued = '1' THEN column2.price ELSE 'No Valued Price' END) as ValuedPrice FROM column2 LEFT JOIN column1 ON column2.product_id=column1.id GROUP BY column2.generic
```

OUTPUT:
199,""

The Output i need is: 199,159

so Grouping it by generic column it give me only 1 row, not 2 as expected.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: grouping on generic will return 1 rowsince all the values are 'SS'...what do you want to group on? tell me the columns..

Comment: What i want get is SS GROUPED AND PRICE, i mean the result need to be, price, ValuedPrice if exist if not the ValuedPrice will be a blank string

Comment: An example of what you would like the output to look like would help a lot

Comment: try my query that i have written below..

Comment: Hey Danyal, thanks for your help, it works, but it give me the price and ValuedPrice with the same Value, as you see the values are different. Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column2.price, (CASE WHEN column2.is_valued = '1' 
THEN column2.price ELSE 'No Valued Price' END) as ValuedPrice FROM column2 
LEFT JOIN column1 ON column2.product_id=column1.id 
GROUP BY column2.generic,column2.price
```

Comment: Hey Danyal, thanks for your help, it works, but it give me the price and ValuedPrice with the same Value, as you see the values are different. Thx